# Where is the proper location to embed IV information for file encryption using Rijndael algorithm?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, rijndael

I'm creating a Rijndael file encryption application. I will using a unique IV for each file encryption.

My question: Where is the proper place to embed the IV info?

My initial thought is to append it at the end of the file's content. Is that a good choice? Any other better option for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the beginning of the file makes more sense (the reader will need it before reading the rest).

But yes, you can safey add it to the output. The IV (and maybe a Salt) is not a secret.